# for row in ws.rows[1:]: TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, python-3.7

The below code is error-ing out, with `openpyxl` and I'm not sure why:

```
                Zip = zip_code.group(0)[:6]

                title_column_name = "Member Address Line 3"
                ws = config.workbook.active
                for row in ws.rows[1:]: # errors out here
                    if row[1].value.find(Zip) != -1:
                        print("Found a matching row! MovieId={0}, Title={1}".format(row[0].value, row[1].value))
```

Below is the output error:

```
    for row in ws.rows[1:]:
TypeError: 'generator' object is not subscriptable
```

**I am simply trying to take my `Zip` value that I'm gathering successfully and get the row where it's found.** *Then I would ultimately like to get a column value of that row.*

Answer (score 1):

Your *ws.rows* is a generator which is not subscriptable.

In order to slice it there are a couple of ways you can go.

[itertools.islice](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) is a good way to go.

```
import itertools
...
<your setup code>
....
    for row in itertools.islice(ws.rows, 1, None):
        ....
        "Now you have skipped the first item"
```

Other options might be using [enumerate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate) and *continue* if the index is 0 or using [next](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#next) to jump over the first before entering the loop.

Comment: Thanks so I used that to replace my line that error-ed out; but now I'm getting:     if row[1].value.find(Zip) != -1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty straightforward: `wc.rows` is not a list (or something that supports `__getitem__`), but a generator. SO the question is, how do you skip the first element? Use `itertools.islice` instead.

```
from itertools import islice

...

for row in islice(ws.rows, 1, None):
```

Compare with `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'][slice(1,None)]`, which is equivalent to `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'][1:]`.

Comment: Thanks so I used that to replace my line that error-ed out; but now I'm getting:     if row[1].value.find(Zip) != -1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find'